# Noob Concern: Problems making a new void method. C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a method in a new class that I made...

```
public void CalcDrinks(bool HealthOption) 
{
    if (HealthOption)
    {
        CostOfBeverage = 5M; 
    }
    else
    {
        CostOfBeverage = 20M; 
    }
}
```

And I keep getting a red squiggly under the void saying... "expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct error"

I'm not sure what I am missing...

Comment: Make sure your method declaration is within a class block. Look in your file for a `public class ...` line and put the method within the curly braces that follow that line, then see if the error goes away.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code above in isolation. Perhaps you can post your entire source code file (if it's not too many lines) since the error is probably external to this method.

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to define the method outside of the class...check your curly braces.

Comment: Can we see the rest of the file? Seems like this might be a contextual problem.

Comment: This error message means you're declaring your method outside your class declaration. So, either you're trying to declare it in the global namespace, or you made an error when writing your class. Could you post the entire code ?

Comment: Your code should look like this, plus whitespaces and line breaks:

class Drinks { public void CalcDrinks(bool healthOption) { //Method } }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the method is inside a class, and that the class/property/other method braces before and after the method line up. Also make sure that the previous statement has a `;` (semicolon).

This problem normally occurs because you have mismatched braces before the method or you have a missing semi-colon:

#### Correct

```
namespace A
{
    public class AA
    {
        public string B {get; set; }    
        public string C {get; set; }
        public void ShowD()
        {
            DoSomething;
        }

    }
}
```

#### Incorrect

```
namespace A
{
    public class AA
    {
        public string B { get; set; }      
        public string C {get; set;    // <--Note missing brace)
        public void ShowD()
        {
            DoSomething;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow... yup.  I did mess up in this way.  I think i'm in love with StackOverflow!  Thanks for the help.  = D

Answer (score 7):

You would get that precisely that error if the method is declared *outside* of a class.

```
namespace Blah
{
    public void CalcDrinks(bool HealthOption) 
    {
        if (HealthOption)
        {
            CostOfBeverage = 5M; 
        }
        else
        {
            CostOfBeverage = 20M; 
        }
    }
}
```

In this snippet, there is no class definition to be seen. Fix it to the below and see that it compiles.

```
public class Foo
{
    private decimal CostOfBeverage;

    public void CalcDrinks(bool HealthOption)
    {
        if (HealthOption)
        {
            CostOfBeverage = 5M;
        }
        else
        {
            CostOfBeverage = 20M;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MonuMan5: Please edit your original question to add your code, rather than one of its answers.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some code in your sample, but based on the error message, your function is declared outside of your class.  The code for your method must be nested within your class.